# Invoke a method in an Object that was created inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I am confused by this question and not even the JavaScript MDN is clarifying the concept for me.

There is a function called invokeMethod and in that function I have to create an Object. The Object includes a Method. I need to invoke the Method in the Object using bracket notation but nothing needs to be returned.

Here is the Question and my code. I keep getting error messages when I try to call the method in the function parentheses.

Question: method is a string that contains the name of a method on the object
Invoke this method using bracket notation.
Nothing needs to be returned.

Input Example:

```
{ foo: function() {} }, 'foo'
```

My code:

```
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  // code here
  const obj = {
    name: 'kung',
    foo: function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  };
}

invokeMethod(obj[foo]);
```

Comment: in `invokeMethod(obj[foo]);` what is the variable `obj`, what is the variable `foo` ? your `invokeMethod` function has two arguments, you call it using one, which doesn't really matter because you use neither of the arguments in the code anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this help.

```js
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  // object definitions
  const obj = {
    name: 'kung',
    foo: function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  };

  // conditional invokation 
  switch(object){
    case "obj":
      if(typeof obj[method] == "function") return obj[method]();
    default:
      console.log("Given object not found!");
    }  
}
// call method
invokeMethod("obj", "foo");
```

***If the object itself is to be passed as parameter:

```js
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
 if(typeof object[method] === "function") 
  object[method]();
 else
  console.log('Invalid function name!');
  }
  
  invokeMethod({ foo: function() {console.log('foo');} }, 'foo');
```

Comment: Here you'll get the objects un-accessible directly, and you can call methods inside them via the invokeMethod().

Comment: I think you need change something here. I mean, of course, the query works, but in a real-time execution, he needs to give an obj and looking the function in that object. if I see your code, you're always returning the function inside the obj const, not the object argument.

Comment: yes @KenrySanchez, I guess I missed that part, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

Look at your function I'm seen that you have as arguments two elements `object` and `method`. So, your functions it's bad doing this

```
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  // code here
  const obj = {
    name: 'kung',
    foo: function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  };
}
```

if you are going to receive the `obj-function`, you should have just this,

```
function invokeMethod(method)
```

Now, Following your example, I'm going to think that you really want to receive the `obj-function`. So, in that case, you should do this.

```
const obj = {
    name: 'kung',
    foo: function(){
      console.log('foo');
    }
  };

function invokeMethod(obj, method) {
  if((method in obj) && typeof obj[method] ==="function"){

    return obj[method]();
  }
}

invokeMethod(obj, 'foo');
```

Comment: That worked! Can you please explain/clarify for me how you were able to reach this solution? Especially the IF statement? That would really help my understanding because I am learning Javascript on my own.

Comment: Of Course. You are looking for a method of the object, so you have to do a query. this query is simple and for that, you use the if statements. Into the `if` you have two operations, `(method in obj)` and `typeof obj[method] ==="function"`. The `in` operator is used for knowledge about the object has a property, in this case, the method. `typeof` is used for knowledge about the type property. it returns the type as a string, so you have to know if the type is a `function`. The final step is returning with bracket notation the function that you are looking for.